# Write to c:\ on another computer

Tags: windows, network-programming

I'm not even sure if this is possible but thought I'd ask anyway. Sorry in advance, I'm sure the question could be worded better.

Is it possible to write a file to the `C:` drive of another computer on your network?

The `C:` drive of `PC1` has a user account with full access rights called `User1`.
`User2` (who is logged into `PC2`) knows the username and password of user account `User1`.
Can `User2` write a file to the `C:` drive of `PC1`.

Hope that makes sense. If you have any question I'll try my best to answer them.

Thank you for everyone's answers.

EDIT

After doing a little more digging I think I've found the answer but I can't test until I get to work tomorrow.

The answer - command line "NET USE Z: \PC1\C$\ /user username1 /pass password1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible unless the other computer is sharing the `C:\` out on the network.  If it is shared, you can access it using `\\computername\share` (where "share" is the name of the c:\ share and "computername" is the network name of your computer.)

As ChrisF points out in the comments, there is a default share named `C$` that you might be able to use.

Comment: What about the "\\machinename\c$" "share" that admins have access to?

Comment: @ChrisF:  True, but those can be disabled.  It really depends on the particular computer.

Comment: @chris - Say all the settings are correct to do this. What kind of thing would i put to a batch file. Say the user account's username is user1 and it's password is password1 and I want to copy the file C:/folder1/file.txt to C:/folder2 on the other PC.

Comment: networking questions like this belong on serverfault, not stackoverflow, but the command you're looking for is [`NET USE s: \\computername\C$ password /USER:username`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true).  After running that command, the  contents of the remote C: drive would be visible as the local S: drive.  Run `NET USE s: /DELETE` when you're done using it to terminate the connection.

Comment: @Ash - you need to look into how you impersonate another user in the language you are using. Then just have "\\machinename\c$\folder2\" as the target path.

Comment: @ben - Will try that tomorrow at work. Thank you in advance if it works :)

Answer (score 1):

If you shared the C: drive on PC1 you could access the network drive just like a local drive...